# Print escape characters in clear text in the MySQL CLI

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that may contain escaped characters in its rows, for example my csv_line_terminator field have values e.g. '\n', '\r\n' etc.

This makes it hard to debug because the MySQL CLI interprets the actual values:

```
mysql> select id,csv_line_terminator from feed_feed;
+----+---------------------+
| id | csv_line_terminator |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | NULL                |
|  2 | NULL                |
|  3 | NULL                |
|  4 | 
              |
+----+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I want it to print:

```
mysql> select id,csv_line_terminator from feed_feed;
+----+---------------------+
| id | csv_line_terminator |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | NULL                |
|  2 | NULL                |
|  3 | NULL                |
|  4 | \r\n                |
+----+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Is there a setting or something in the MySQL CLI to get this behaviour instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can custom your output with the `PAGER` command like explained [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/06/23/neat-tricks-for-the-mysql-command-line-pager/).
The difficulty would be to find out a base command that translate the endline chars into their visual representation.
A tricky way would be to create a php or python script (or other language) and pass it to pager

In your php script you put

`$argv = $_SERVER['argv'];
$argc = $_SERVER['argc'];
if($argc > 1){
   str_replace("/n",'/n',$argv[1]); 
   str_replace("/r",'/r',$argv[1]);
   str_replace("/t",'/t',$argv[1]);
}`

and then in a `.sh` file put

```
#!/bin/sh
php yourfile.php
```

and set your PAGER to `pager yourshfil.sh`